# Export Button using JQuery not working via Microsoft Excel (downloaded via Mobile)

Tags: jquery, excel

I have a export button (for xls) using JQuery. The export button is working on PCs/Laptops. But when on mobile version, when users downloaded it, it cannot be opened by 'Microsoft Excel Apps'. The file that be downloaded can be only open on apps called WPS Office. When it opened by Microsoft Excel, it popup error ("The version is not support/ File can't be open".

Here is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

//getting data from our table
var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
var table_div = document.getElementById('table_id');
var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
a.download = 'exported_wastagegraph_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999) + 1000000) + '.xls';
a.click();
});
});
```

Here is my button on HTML

```
<div class="box">
<center><input id="btnExport" type="submit" class="button" value="  EXPORT  "></center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is saved as the old *.xls format, it can't be opened by mobile versions of Excel. Mobile Excel needs *.xlsx format

Comment: yeah, it comes with error "it can't be opened" or "not support". so i need to change (a.download = //somecode '.xls';) to (a.download = //somecode '.xlsx';) ?

Comment: the difference is more than just a letter in the file extension. xlsx is a completely different file format. If jQuery produces .xls then just changing the file extension won't make a difference. If, however, jQuery produces a real .xlsx file, and you have named it .xls, then that would account for the errro, too. So, do you KNOW what format jQuery produces?

Comment: The format for my JQuery produces is for xls only, i have changed the data-type for xlsx. but still the same error come out.